# How can I uncomment line with empty space?

Tags: sed

Suppose I have a file with this content:

```
#plugin = eosio::producer_plugin
#plugin = eosio::producer_api_plugin
```

And if I try to uncomment value by using sed, it will fail:

```
sed -E '/plugin.*(producer_plugin)/s/^#//g' file.ini
```

To notice, there is an empty space before #.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to skip space characters at the beginning of the line you can do:

```
/^ *A/
```

Caret, space, asterisk, first significant character.
What would mean "At the beginning of the line, there is zero or more spaces, followed by the letter A".

In your example

```
sed -E '/plugin.*(producer_plugin)/s/^ *#//g' file.ini
```

Read here for description of special characters:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended

Comment: Note that the `g` flag at the end of the `s///` command is useless when you anchor the pattern to the start or end of the line.  Also, the parenthesis in the pattern seems ineffective, and the `-E` option is not really needed.